# Binary Search - Output is not displaying after code compiles and runs

Tags: c++, c++11, search, binary-search

I'm just now learning about binary search in class and the code below is simply an example because I'm trying to understand it better. So with that said this code is compiling but not displaying any output and because of my lack of knowledge of Binary search I do not know why there isn't any output. Can someone please point in the direction of really well written tutorials, please? Or help indicate what is wrong with the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{
    int thisArray[] = { 99,86,44,55,78,63,0,32,11 };
    int num = 0;

    int n = 0;

    int first;
    int last;
    int middle;
    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    cout << "Enter the total number of elements\n";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Entered " << n << "number.\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> thisArray[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter a number to find.\n";
    cin >> num;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (thisArray[middle] < num) {
            first = middle + 1;
        }
        else if (thisArray[middle] == num ) {
            cout << num << " found at location " << middle + 1 << "\n";
            break;
        }
        else {
            last = middle - 1;
        }
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

edit:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{
    //this is my binary search
    int thisArray[10] = { 0,11,32,44,55,63,78,86,99 };
    int i = 0; //index of the array
    int n = 0; //variable of number that will be looked for
    int first = 0;
    int last = SIZE - 1;
    int middle;
    int pos = -1;
    bool found = false;
    int count = 0;
    while (found) {

        cout << "Enter a number to look for.\n";
        cin >> n;


        while (first <= last) {
            middle = first + last / 2;
            if (thisArray[middle] == n) {

                pos = middle;
                cout << "item found at " << middle + 1 << "\n";

                exit(0);
            }
            else if (thisArray[middle] > n) {
                last = middle - 1;
            }
            else {
                first = middle + 1;
            }//endif
        }//end while
    }//end big while
    //if()


    return 0;
}
```

I got it. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: It would help to step through the code and see how it works in a debugger. You do need a sorted array for a binary search though, so perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Post your input and expected output. Binary search only works for *sorted* arrays, BTW.

Comment: Hi Retired Ninja, thank you for your help. I'll sort it immediately.

Comment: MFisher, that's my issue..the code isn't generating any output except "Press any button to continue."

Answer (score 2):

It's not outputting anything because `first == 0` and `last == -1`. Hence `first <= last` is never true and the loop body is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

you know what ? how can you even be using binary search if the array is not sorted properly to use binary search property ... 
and please , stop answering question like Jack meagher style, I hate answer that isn't directly addressing the problem , its kinda restating the question ...

Comment: Well, like I said, I am unfamiliar with this type of sort so that's why, but thank you for making me aware of my mistake.

Comment: what do you mean by type of sort :/? the binary search algo is fine. just sort the array before you are using it so you have the monotone property

Answer (score 0):

Simple

Change `last = n - 1;` to `last = SIZE - 1;`

Or calculate `last = n - 1;` after u have accepted the value of `n`

Also the array needs to be sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Now though the code was an example that I had found the for loop was not working correctly for me, so I got rid of it. And for iteration I implemented a do-while loop. However, the code the works now.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{
    //this is my binary search
    int thisArray[10] = { 0,11,32,44,55,63,78,86,99 };
    int i = 0; //index of the array
    int n = 0; //variable of number that will be looked for
    int first = 0;
    int last = SIZE - 1;
    int middle;
    int pos = -1;
    bool found = false;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number to look for.\n";
        cin >> n;


        while (first <= last) {
            middle = first + last / 2;
            if (thisArray[middle] == n) {

                pos = middle;
                cout << "item found at " << middle + 1;
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (thisArray[middle] > n) {
                last = middle - 1;
            }
            else {
                first = middle + 1;
            }//endif
        }//end while
    } while (found = true);
    return 0;
}
```